# Accessing an array's elements directly from a pointer/address

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would like to:

- pass a pointer to an array of ints to a method,
- use the values within the method,
- resize the array within the method,
- and then continue using the array outside the method.

My method declaration has func(int** arr_address), and I call the method like func(&arr). One way to do this, which works, is to assign local variables inside my method, but this seems clumsy. The method I am attempting to use is to access the array element directly, like *arr_address[1], but this seems to apply the [1] offset to the memory address of the pointer, rather than the address of where the array data starts in memory.

Here is a simple program with output to illustrate two different methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int** arr1_address, int** arr2_address)
{
    int* arr1_local = *arr1_address;

    arr1_local[1]=2;     // Works
    *arr2_address[1]=22; // (*) Writes to position 0 of wrong array!

    // These realloc() calls were incorrect in the original question
    //arr1_address = (int**)realloc(*arr1_address, 3*sizeof(int));
    //arr2_address = (int**)realloc(*arr2_address, 3*sizeof(int));
    *arr1_address = realloc(*arr1_address, 3*sizeof(int));
    *arr2_address = realloc(*arr2_address, 3*sizeof(int));

    //arr1_local[2] = 3;
    //*arr2_address[2] = 33;
}

int main()
{
    int* arr1;
    int* arr2;

    arr1 = (int*)calloc( 2, sizeof(int) );
    arr2 = (int*)calloc( 2, sizeof(int) );

    arr1[0] = 1;
    arr2[0] = 11;

    std::cout << "arr1, before func(): " << &arr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "arr2, before func(): " << &arr2 << std::endl;

    func(&arr1, &arr2);

    std::cout << "arr1, after func(): " << &arr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "arr2, after func(): " << &arr2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "arr1: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr1[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr1[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr1[2] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "arr2:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr2[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr2[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr2[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like:

```
arr1, before func(): 0xffffcc08 // Note offset after arr2 location in memory
arr2, before func(): 0xffffcc00
arr1, after func(): 0xffffcc08  // realloc did not move the arrays
arr2, after func(): 0xffffcc00

arr1:
22                              // Note line marked (*) wrote here instead of arr2[1]
2
66594

arr2:
11
0
66554
```

I am pretty sure that I understand why the line marked (*) works the way it does. I would like to know if there is a similar method of addressing the [1] element of arr2 directly from its address.

(Apologies if this has been asked before, I have read quite a few answers and tried my best to investigate before asking.)

Edit: better title, fix mistake in realloc() lines

Comment: Use std::vector.

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Seriously, use `std::vector`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am not able to use vector due to requirements outside my control.

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: What could I do differently in the future to avoid the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a similar method of addressing the `[1]` element of `arr2` directly from its address.

The reason that you see the behavior when `[]` is applied to `arr2_address` is that `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. You can force the precedence that you want by applying parenthesis:

```
(*arr2_address)[1] = 22;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not understood this. The line (*) now works, but the equivalent line at the very end of func() causes a seg fault when uncommented.

Comment: That's because `arr1_address = (int**)realloc(*arr1_address, 3*sizeof(int));` reassignment should be `*arr1_address = realloc(*arr1_address, 3*sizeof(int));` (no cast, asterisk).

Comment: Thank you! I just worked out the asterisk part. The no-cast part is obvious now that you mention it. I will correct the code in the question. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not understanding what pointer points to what data in a pointer-to-a-pointer construction. If you have more than one level of pointers, stop and [draw a picture](https://www.google.com/search?q=pointer+to+pointer).

Normally you almost never should use pointers to pointers though. This case is no exception. You want to pass by reference. Use actual references for that.

```
void func(int*& arr1, int*& arr2)
{
    arr1[0] = 42; // simple, easy
    arr1 = realloc (arr1, 42*sizeof(int)); // simple, easy
    free (arr2); // simple, easy
    arr2 = malloc (42*sizeof(int)); // simple, easy
}
```

Comment: The top google result for "cpp pass by reference" only gives examples like `func(int& arr1)` which I am more familiar with. Is the only difference here the type, i.e. working on `int` values instead of `int*` values? So `int**&` would technically be valid (but not necessarily useful) too? Great job "answering the question you wish I had asked", btw!

Comment: @Snaptastic When you pass something by reference, you can modify that thing in a function, and changes are reflected back in the caller. In `func(int& arr1)`, you pass an `int` by reference. In  `func(int*& arr1)`, you pass an `int*` by reference. `arr1` in `main` is the thing you want to pass, it's of type `int*`, so `int*&` is an appropriate parameter type. You don't have an `int**` variable in `main`, but if you wanted to use one and pass it by reference, `int**&` would be the parameter type.